# Power BI/ Power Query: increment the highest number in one sheet based on conditions in another sheet

Tags: excel, powerbi, vlookup, increment, powerquery

I am trying to filter the highest number in each of four columns in Power BI.

For specific occurences of a string in the column of another excel file loaded in my Power BI, I want to select one of the four number and increment it.

I have several difficutlies:
- I cannot select the highest number
- I do not know how to create a costum column referencing another sheet
- I do not know how to "store" a value dinamically for each occurence

Here is the input excel workbook:

[image: input]

Here is the excel workbook with data to increment (in Power Bi I already suprressed the strings, seperated my column in four columns each needing to be incremented, becauseI did not know to do it in another way. Having strings character at the begining for example, was a clear issue to increment).

[image: inout 2]

Here is the resulting excel: each time a specific name appears I add one to the higest value of each iteam in my column :

[image: OUTPUT]

I need to search for the highest number in each of these columns:
[image: searching for the highest number in each column]

When I see "*ItalyB*", "*ItalyZ*", "*UKY*" or "*UKM*", I need to increment the highest number. 
The first incrementation will be equal to the highest number from the column + 1, and the second, to the result + 1.

The highest number between ABE0000 and ABE4000, once found, I add one to AB for each "ItalyZ" elements. i.e AB0003 for one element "ItalyZ", the next "ItalyZ" wil get AB0004

The highest number between ABE4000 and ABE9000, once found, I add one to AB for each "ItalyB" elements. i.e AB4003 for one element "ItalyB", the next "ItalyB" wil get AB0004

The highest number between BC0000 and BC4000, once found, I add one to BC for each "UKY" elements. i.e BC0003 for one element "UKY", the next "UKY" wil get BC0004

The highest number between BC4000 and BC9000, once found, I add one to for each "UKM" elements. i.e BC4003 for one element "UKM", the next "UKM" wil get BC4004.

[image]

I do not know how to do that. I have added a date:
[image]

And I am trying to increment given the date, but I am having difficutlies:
[image: increment]

Comment: How do these two sheets correlate? What does `ItalyB` have to do with the first sheet?

Comment: These ranges could be seen as "occurences" happenning in specific zones (four zones). I modified my question to make it clearer. In the first sheet, I look for the "last" and thus "highest" occurence in a region (such as ItalyZ, which correspond to the column "ABE range low") and I keep incrementing the last highest occurence.

Comment: Is the objective of this to do reporting? Or do you actally need to keep track of these incremented columns over time? Power BI is good for reporting and generating non-permanent read-only attributes, but if you actually need to store these id's for other purposes, you need a database. You could probably do what you want in Power BI but it may be more appropriate to do this in a database.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to a database. Each month I have to do this merger and look for the highest value...and thus doing it through Power Query instead of a manual search look would be a massive step forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't understand your question as it is not explained well (you are directly referring to column codes 'ABE0000' etc. without showing which excel or sheet you are referring)

But I can answer one part which I understood. Create a new column which increments highest number in it by 1.

Lets call the calculated column as ABERangeLowIncrement:

ABERangeLowIncrement = 
var maxABERangeLow = 
Calculate(max('ABE Range Low'),ALL(TableName'ABE Range Low'))

return
if(TableName'ABE Range Low' = maxABERangeLow,maxABERangeLow +1, TableName'ABE Range Low')

Comment: What I understand is that basically you need to create keys for 4 types of data (ItalyZ,ItalyB,UKY,UKM). ItalyZ key starts with ABE0, ItalyB with AB4 and so on)
Do you have any other column like date when the data gets added?
Why don't you create calculated column which ranks these on date when it gets added? In that case you don't have to maintain a separate input and output file

Comment: So which file you receive periodically? One with all the data except keys or the one which mentions only keys

Comment: Do the key number keep changing everytime? For e.g. Row With snurp value ciocaloto will always be ABE0003 or will it change. And is the key  ordering based on the order in which data gets added?

Comment: I will suggest you to add a column for date or month when data got added.... You can do it once for your historic data as well... Then you can create calculated column which will create the key as you want based on rank of date or month it got added.... For ex. Let's say you have 2 rows for italyz for Feb and March... Create calculated column which maps prefix... In this case ABE.. Create a column which ranks your row based on date... It will give rank 1 to Feb and 2 to March... Concatenate the results and create your key... In that case you don't need to maintain other file

Comment: What I understand is that business is giving you files incrementally... They give you each month Data and you append manually.... Now to answer your qs... Yes the data that you already have you can add dates to them it will be one time work.... Even if you don't know actual date you know the order with help of keys... After this you can append your new data with new dates and key will generate automatically in Power BI

Comment: It won't be same fake date, but different fake date for each different key... You can generate that in excel one time....

Comment: In excel ? Not in Power BI ? My goal is to everything in PBI to just import the file each month.

Comment: Yes that is also possible

Comment: I am trying but sadly failling to implement this on PBI. I have issues with the power query formula counting the range on specific conditions. I also do not know how to "bring" it to the other sheet after that. I added the problematic query the question